# How can I get a confidence level on a voting system's output?

Tags: confidence-interval, voting-system

I'm running a tournament, which tries to rank players as they compete against each other.  I'm having problems with the fact that the rankings are changing if I run a tournament multiple times.

To be more specific:

1. Players are selected to compete against each other in a game.
2. I run many games (thousands to millions).  Each game gives us a ranking of the players that competed.
3. I take all of the scores from all of the games and run them through a [voting system](https://wiki.electorama.com/wiki/Voting_system#List_of_systems).  I've used different forms of voting system, but one I often use is Maximized Affirmed Majorities.

I want a confidence level for this ranking to know if I need to run more games or not.  I want to be confident that the final ranking is accurate (even if I were to rerun the tournament)

Is this possible?  Can I make it independent of the voting system used?

Comment: If I got you correctly, without knowing what job the voting system does, it is not possible to answer the question. For example, if the voting is just an arithmetic mean of the player ranks, it is one story, if it takes something like a weighted mean, it is another. I guess more details will help answer it.

Comment: Ok, that's good to know.  My system actually supports more than one voting system which is why I was hoping for an agnostic solution.  I'll add a specific voting system.

Comment: @AlexeyBurnakov If I were to run the voting system each round, and track how much it changes from round to round, or take subsets of the games and run the system on it, would that make it easier?

Comment: As for me, I know how to build a CI for average, which would be enough to test a hypothesis on a certain level of significance. That is quite basic, but powerful. In your case, matters are more complex. I am not sure there is a solid statistic for the measure you cited (I am not an expert in this field). On the other hand, if you can run countless simulations, I would suggest making an empirical study of how large your samples should be to ensure that, e.g., 95% of times final user ranks stay the same in both train and test simulation.